# How to get an object with wildscard bucket key in aws js-sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, ceph, aws-sdk-nodejs

I use [ceph](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/giant/radosgw/s3/#api) to store my object.
I just download the file from other rescources and store it in `ceph` with unique filename and the original postfix.
I wander if i can retrive an object without the postfix  like:

```
// just assume the file path is `bucket/unique_id.jpg`
let file = require('fs').createWriteStream('image.png');
s3.getObject({
    Bucket: 'bucket',
    Key: 'unique_id*',
}).createReadStream().pipe(file);
```

Comment: No. The only operation that supports multiple objects is deleteObjects().

Comment: @jarmod Thanks a lot. So i can only do this by listing and find the list the full key and then getObject with the key ?